# Appium Server not connected and throwing org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: appium

I have recently started mobile devices automation on appium with the java language.

I am trying to run the initial setup code through program it is returning this failure message.

**Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect**

When Manual run Appium server it doesn't have any errors and server started; the android apk file is installed.

Below is my code; Eclipse doesn't show any errors. I use Android Emulator for this Initial test. Appium and Java Project code in same host machine.

```java
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
    WebDriver AppWebDriver = null;
    AppiumDriver ApUMDriver = null;
    AndroidDriver AppiumURLDriver;

    URL Serverurl;

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DesiredCapabilities Appiumcapabiliy = new DesiredCapabilities();

    File appDir = new File("c:\ApkbuildsDir");
    File app = new File(appDir, "xxx.apk");

    Appiumcapabiliy.setCapability("devicename","Device11");
    Appiumcapabiliy.setCapability("platformname","Android");
    Appiumcapabiliy.setCapability("platformVersion","4.2.2");

    Appiumcapabiliy.setCapability("app-package","packagename");
    Appiumcapabiliy.setCapability("app-activity","activityscreen");
    Appiumcapabiliy.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    Serverurl = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
    AppWebDriver = new AndroidDriver(Serverurl,Appiumcapabiliy);

    AppWebDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    ApUMDriver.findElement(By.name("My Card"));

}
```

Could you please guide me how to eliminate this server connect error through program.

Regards, Kiran

Answer (score 1):

Looks like "Appium server" instance is NOT running in your machine. That is, `http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub`

Please start the Appium server on 4723 port and try execute your code.

Comment: I have changed the port no to 4788 , it is working fine.